# Why it isnt it possible to do Set <Object> = new TreeSet <String>

Tags: java, collections, tree, set

Question: Why it isnt it possible to do `Set <Object> = new TreeSet <String>`? Why do I need to add ? extends.

Feeling like it is a set of objects and not one entity so it can get any type of collection, but the right side of the equation knows only to understand collection of strings

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/wildcards.html  there is a good explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a `Set<Object>` you can add instances of `Integer`, `String` or any other reference type.

To a `TreeSet<String>` you can only add instances of `String`.

Therefore the compiler doesn't allow assigning a `TreeSet<String>` to a `Set<Object>`, since it would allow you to add any reference type to a `TreeSet` that should only hold `String`s.